# how to save multiple selected checkboxlist to database asp .net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have two checkboxlists CandidateName and Payment,  and a dropdownlist. User can do multiple selections in checkboxlists and one selection at dropdownlist. I am populating those data of chechboxlists and dropdownlist to Panel nested inside UpdatePanel where gridview exist.. When I click on Add Button to open up Panel, all data is properly populating. When I tried to save multiple selected checkedboxlists through "for loop" at debugging, it is not going inside the loop to accumulate checked data with comma to save at database. Instead, after chekcing  "if (cblPayment1.Items[j].Selected == true)", it skips over to another query statement. Please help me advise.

```
 protected void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string strcbl1 = string.Empty;
        string strcbl2 = string.Empty;
        compCon = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        compCon.Open();


        for (int i = 0; i < cblCandidateName1.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (cblCandidateName1.Items[i].Selected ==true)
            {
                strcbl1 = strcbl1 + cblCandidateName1.Items[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < cblPayment1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (cblPayment1.Items[j].Selected == true)
            {
                strcbl2 += cblPayment1.Items[j].Value.ToString() + ",";
            }
        }


       string InsertSchedule = "INSERT INTO ScheduleEmail(CANDIDATE_ID, PAYMENT_ID,     TEMPLATE_ID)VALUES(@strCID, @strPID, @strCourseID)";
        SqlCommand InsertScheduleCommand = new SqlCommand(InsertSchedule, compCon);
        InsertScheduleCommand.Connection = compCon;


        InsertScheduleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strCID", strcbl1);
        InsertScheduleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strPID", strcbl2);
        InsertScheduleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strCourseID", strCourseID);

        InsertScheduleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        compCon.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowPopUpMsg("Data is failed to save in table. Please contact your system administrator \n" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    { 
    DispalyGridViewScheduleEmail();

    compCon.Close();
    }

}
```

THis is my HTML Code.

```
<!--Panel to add new record--><asp:Panel ID="panelAddNew" runat="server" 
style="display:none; background-color:gray;"        ForeColor="Black" Width="500" Height="550">
<asp:Panel ID="panelAddNewTitle" runat="server" 
 style="cursor:move;font-family:Tahoma;                       
 padding:2px;" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="White" Height="25">
<b>Add New</b></asp:Panel>
 <table width="100%" style="padding:5px">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Select Candidate Name(s)</b></td>
                <td><b>:</b></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCandidateName1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="table">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Select Payments</b></td>
                <td><b>:</b></td>
                <td>
                   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblPayment1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><b>Course Name</b></td>
                <td><b>:</b></td>
                <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourseName" runat="server">      </asp:DropDownList>            


                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
            <div align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew2" runat="server" Width="70" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddNew_Click"  ValidationGroup="add"/>
            &nbsp;

            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel1" runat="server" Width="70" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="Cancel_Click" ValidationGroup="add"/>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>   
        <!--End of Panel to add new record-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your `for` blocks will not be executed at the last item of `cblCandidateName1.Items` and `cblPayment1.Items` because of this condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cblCandidateName1.Items.Count-1; i++)
```

and

```
for (int j = 0; j < cblPayment1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
```

You need to change both of your `for` blocks to the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < cblCandidateName1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (cblCandidateName1.Items[i].Selected ==true)
    {
        strcbl1 = strcbl1 + cblCandidateName1.Items[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < cblPayment1.Items.Count; j++)
{
    if (cblPayment1.Items[j].Selected == true)
    {
        strcbl2 += cblPayment1.Items[j].Value.ToString() + ",";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that `cblPayment1.Items[j].Selected` is always false even though you check some of the payment checkboxlist. The possible cause could be that you populate `cblPayment1` items in `Page_Load` method but not inside `if (!this.IsPostBack)` block

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cblPayment1.DataSource = .... ;
    cblPayment1.DataBind();
}
```

When you click the save button, `Page_Load` method will be executed first before `btnAddNew_Click`, so `cblPayment1` will be repopulated and all of its items won't be selected when you reach `btnAddNew_Click` method. You need to change `Page_Load` code as the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        cblPayment1.DataSource = .... ;
        cblPayment1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed minus 1 and debugged. It is still not going inside "if" statement. thank for your help.

Comment: Did you check if `cblPayment1.Items[j].Selected` is actually true?

Comment: it is true. I selected 2 of checkboxlist of payment.

Comment: ,Thank. That make sense. I didn't put code in Page_Load. That's why it wasn't looping at all. It is working now. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to not use string concatenation in a loop in a way you shown in question. It's bad habit and leads to performance problems at later time since every concatenation reallocates new memory for string and then copies it into that place.

And how about using some lambdas in this code?
It will be dramatically simplified like that:

```
strcbl1=string.Join(",", cblCandidateName1.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected));
strcbl2=string.Join(",", cblPayment1.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try not to use string concatenation in a loop in a way you have shown in your question. It's a bad habit and leads to performance problems at a later time since every concatenation reallocates new memory for string and then copies it into that place.

And how about using some lambdas in this code? It will be dramatically simplified like that:

```
strcbl1 = string.Join(",", cblCandidateName1.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected));

strcbl2 = string.Join(",", cblPayment1.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected));
```